RDP Connect using Windows RDP to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am relatively inexperienced with Ubuntu.
I would like to access an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from a Windows 10/11 system via RDP.
The access works without any problems via the options provided by Ubuntu (Remote Login), unfortunately I cannot access the home folder or the settings via these.

I have always found great support from this website https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19814, regarding connecting windows and ubuntu via xrdp.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question but have you tried using the Remote Desktop option instead of Remote Login as this will let you access the current running instance?

@mr_rumpler
The “remote desktop” is unfortunately not an option as several users must be able to access the system via an individual user.
I have now used XRDP and it works, albeit with a slight delay at the moment. And only with the Gnome UI instead of Ubuntu's own.
